# Softwares for clustering of machines

Tags: server, software-recommendation, cluster

I have taken up a project in which I have to setup a server(any kind of server) and desktop computers such that the server can use the processors of other computers for computations(or other tasks) when they are in idle state or while low usage of the processors.

Can someone please suggest me some opensource software for that will be required or some ideas about how to do it? I tried to see some projects like Beowulf Cluster and TORQUE but I didn't understand much.

Thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an attempt to develop an *ad hoc* clustering solution for Ubuntu from within the Community called [easy-ubuntu-clustering](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/easy-ubuntu-clustering). But it seems it did not pass the dicussion phase.

More than software, Clustering is above all a matter of methodology. Setting up a [Beowulf cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf_cluster) in particular is mostly about setting up the mechanisms by which nodes communicate and share resources. There are protocols for both tasks; [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) in particular is used in most Linux based solutions.

Various guides can be found on the web presenting different methods; a quick collection:

- A bio-informatics graduate from the Netherlands produced a [detailed guide](http://byobu.info/article/Building_a_simple_Beowulf_cluster_with_Ubuntu/) based on [MPICH](http://www.mpich.org/) for communication and [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_(protocol)) for asset sharing.
- [Advanced Linux](http://linuxadvanced.blogspot.com/2012/04/building-beowulf-cluster-with-ubuntu.html) provides an alternative (and shorter) guide, also based on MPICH and NFS.
- At [Linux.com](http://www.linux.com/community/blogs/133-general-linux/9401) there is a quick and simple guide for Ubuntu 8.04 convering solely communication (with an earlier version of MPICH) that may be worth checking out.
- [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-beowulf-cluster-using-ubuntu-12-04-vps-instances) present a VPN based method for their private network product that also uses MPI.